# What's wrong with using Identity monad with mmultP when using repa?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, repa

I do not understand why this program using [repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa):

```
import Data.Array.Repa
import Data.Array.Repa.Algorithms.Matrix
import Data.Functor.Identity

go = runIdentity $ do
  let mat = fromListUnboxed (ix2 2 2) [1..4]
  let ins = fromListUnboxed (ix2 2 1) [1, 1]
  mmultP mat ins
```

is giving me the following warning:

```
Data.Array.Repa: Performing nested parallel computation sequentially.
  You've probably called the 'compute' or 'copy' function while another
  instance was already running. This can happen if the second version
  was suspended due to lazy evaluation. Use 'deepSeqArray' to ensure
  that each array is fully evaluated before you 'compute' the next one.
```

I have no nested computations, I didn't call `compute` or `copy`, and everything that I used to do the computation is inside the same monad. Is it something to do with lazy evaluation? If so, how do I make the parallel computation happen while using the Identity monad (to keep the overall computation pure) ?

For reference, replacing `runIdentity` with `runST` makes it work, although in either case the specific monad's functionality isn't being used at all.

Comment: Looking inside the source code, I see that `mmultP` calls `computeP`, which calls `unsafePerformIO`. I'm not very experienced with this, but might there be an incompatibility between `unsafePerformIO` and the `Identity` monad (maybe `Identity`'s behaviour with laziness) ?

Comment: @madjar I have no idea. I don't see how.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for having the `Monad` constraint in `computeP` and similar parallel operations is to force sequential computation where required. This is described in [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell], in subsection *Monads and computeP*.

In your case, the problem seems to be caused by the internal implementation of [`mmultP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-algorithms-3.4.0.2/docs/src/Data-Array-Repa-Algorithms-Matrix.html#mmultP):

```
mmultP  :: Monad m
        => Array U DIM2 Double 
        -> Array U DIM2 Double 
        -> m (Array U DIM2 Double)

mmultP arr brr 
 = [arr, brr] `deepSeqArrays` 
   do   trr      <- transpose2P brr
        let (Z :. h1  :. _)  = extent arr
        let (Z :. _   :. w2) = extent brr
        computeP 
         $ fromFunction (Z :. h1 :. w2)
         $ \ix   -> R.sumAllS 
                  $ R.zipWith (*)
                        (unsafeSlice arr (Any :. (row ix) :. All))
                        (unsafeSlice trr (Any :. (col ix) :. All))
```

It calls first `transpose2P` and then `computeP`, and `transpose2P` internally calls `computeUnboxedP`. If you use the `Identity` monad, there is no sequencing forced, so both these parallel computations can run in parallel, hence the nested parallelism.

If you want to keep things pure and also don't want to use `ST`, you can replace `Identity` with [`Eval`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#t:Eval), which is a strict version of `Identity`:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
...
go = runEval $ do ...
```

Comment: Thank you. My confusion with this rooted in the `Identity` monad not having sequencing forced. Why? Isn't it a monad that uses `>>=` to sequence?

Comment: Monads describe computations, but in general not how they're evaluated. For some monads the order is enforced (`IO`, `ST`, `Eval`, ...), but for some monads not (`Reader`, `Identity`, ...). Haskell's lazy evaluation still applies, so if the order isn't forced, computations are still evaluated lazily. In particular, `Identity` is a monad that doesn't do anything at all, it only give monadic interface for pure computations.